# Negative solution to $x^2=2^x$

Tags: functions, exponential-function

Just out of curiosity I was trying to solve the equation $x^2=2^x$, initially I thought there would be just the two solutions $x=2$ and $x=4$, but wolfram shows that the two equations intersect at not 2 but 3 locations, the third being a negative value of $x$. The third solution isn't obvious like the other two, so I just have a few questions about the negative solution. Is it rational? is it commonly represented with a greek letter? If it is irrational is there a way to approximate it?

Comment: It might help to note that the (negative of the) solution you seek is the positive solution to $x=2^{-x/2}$.

Comment: $-\frac{23}{30}$ is a very good approximation.

Comment: Well $x^2$ is always positive so if there is a negative solution it would be x = -y where y is positive  and $y^2 = 1/2^y$. So y < 1.  If g(x) = $y^2 - 1/2^y$ then g(x) is continuous.  g(0) = -1. g(1) = 1/2.  So there is a solution in there.

Comment: Definitely not rational as it that would imply 2 (or 1/2) would have rational roots.

Comment: @fleablood by a negative solution, I meant the negative value of x for which $x^2=2^x$

Comment: Yes, I know.  Why do you point that out?

Comment: A negative solution to $x^2 = 2^x$ would be the negative equivalent to a positive solution to $y^2 = 2^{-y}$.

Comment: $2^2 = 4$  $(1/2)^2 = 1/4$.  That is not a solution.  At least not to my equation.  It is to $x^2 = 2^x$ but we already knew that.  We are looking for a negative solution to that.

Comment: @Peter *what* argument can't be valid without restrictions?

Comment: @user217339 It shows once again that making a proper graph to start out with, can do miracles. It clearly show 3 solutions...

Comment: @peter The *negative* solution can not be rational.  If x  = -y is the negative solution then $y^2 = (1/2)^y$ where y is positive.  y can not be 1 or greater as that'd make $y^2 \ge 1$ while $(1/2)^y <\le 1/2$.  So if y is less than 1 and rational it mean a root of 2 is rational, which is impossible. (All solutions must be irrational or integers, by the way.  The positive solutions are greater than 1 and happen to be integers.  The negative solution is between 0 and -1 so can not be an integer.)

Comment: OK, so you only looked at the negative solution.

Comment: @peter.  NO!!!  I looked at both positive solutions.  They were in the OP for !!!!'s sake! So of course I looked at them! The OP was asking about the *negative* solutions! so I was hypothesizing about the *strictly negative* solution.  I wasn't "not looking at" the positive solutions.  The positive solutions are known so there is nothing to say about them.

Comment: If you look for a "standard notation" for the negative solution, you might want to check out the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Using it, the negative solution is something like $x=-2W((\ln 2)/2)/\ln 2$.

Comment: Is there a name for this number or it part of a certain set of numbers, e.g. negative solutions to $a^x=x^a$, for $a\beq 2$

Comment: @peter was that approx calculated by simply narrowing the range (-1, 0) to get closer to the solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose , $gcd(a,b)=1$ , $x=\frac{a}{b}$ and $x^2=2^x$

We have $$a^2=b^2\times 2^{a/b}$$

implying

$$a^{2b}=b^{2b}\times 2^a$$

This is impossible, if $gcd(a,b)=1$ and $b>1$. The negative solution is obviously not an integer.

If $x$ is irrational algebraic, then $2^x$ is transcendental, but $x^2$ is not.

So, $x$ , the negative solution, must be a transcendental number.

Comment: Doesn't answer how it is approximated in the first place.

Comment: See my comment above for an approximation.

Answer (score 3):

So we have $x^2 = 2^x$. Taking the square root of both sides and assume the solution is negative gives $x=-\sqrt{2}^x$. We can then establish a recursive sequence, $x_n = -\sqrt2^{x_{n-1}}$. Assuming that this converges gives us the answer, $x=-\sqrt2 ^{-\sqrt2 ^ {-\sqrt2 ^\cdots}}$. After five iterations, we get $$x\approx-0.76961847524.$$ Substituting the answer back in we get, $$2^{-0.76961847524} = 0.58657257487 \approx 0.59231259743 =(-0.76961847524)^2.$$