# Solve $x^2 = 2^x$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, diophantine-equations

One can see that the solutions are $x=2, 4$ and $x=-0.77$(approximately) seen from the graph. I am posting this to find if there is a way to solve this and find solutions like polynomial equations. Thanks !!!

Comment: Equations that have the unknown in an exponent and in a base can not be solved symbolically.

Comment: see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544703

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), an inverse of $we^w$. We have $$x=\sqrt{2}^x=e^{x\ln\sqrt{2}},\,-x\ln\sqrt{2}e^{-x\ln\sqrt{2}}=-\ln\sqrt{2},\,x=-\frac{-W\left(-\ln\sqrt{2}\right)}{\ln\sqrt{2}}.$$ That's the theory, anyway. Like complex exponentiation, the Lambert W-function has multiple branches in $\mathbb{C}$. But the Lambert W function is of interest because many equations' solutions are expressible in terms of it.